# spring-boot-legacy with H2-Console

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot, h2

I cloned the project https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-legacy/ to see if I can deploy it in tomcat 5.5, it was deployed successfully.

Because I need H2 embedded database, I added H2 (version: 1.4.196) as a dependency with this configuration in application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
# H2 Web Console (H2ConsoleProperties)
# Enable the console.
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
# Path at which the console will be available.
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Anyway after deploying the application again in tomcat 5.5 this error comes up :

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-02-01 14:18:28.140 ERROR 5280 --- [080-Processor25] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Registration$Dynamic
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(SpringBootContextLoaderListener.java:61) [spring-boot-legacy-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3795) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:884) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:523) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1285) [catalina.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:458) [commons-modeler-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1397) [catalina-manager.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217) [catalina-manager.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174) [catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879) [tomcat-http.jar:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665) [tomcat-http.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528) [tomcat-util.jar:5.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81) [tomcat-util.jar:5.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689) [tomcat-util.jar:5.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Registration$Dynamic
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Registration$Dynamic
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.h2Console(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c965331.CGLIB$h2Console$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c965331$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4600180c.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c965331.h2Console(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Registration$Dynamic
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284) ~[na:na]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Legacy is for Servlet 2.5 containers, tomcat 5.5 is a servlet 2.4 container.

Comment: @M.Deinum Like I said I already succeeded in deploying the WAR when I cloned the project, It's the H2-console alone that creates this error, in fact when I comment the parameter **spring.h2.console.enabled=true** the error goes away.

Comment: Regardless. The requirement is Servlet API 2.5, you might not be using those features and that is why it deploys. You are now using features which actually require that minimum version of the Servlet API and things break.

Answer (score 1):

**Try it in application.properties**

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.driver

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

**And in POM.XML, put the dependencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```